# Javascript arrow function doesn't work as intended?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

The following code works as expected:

```
let letter = {
    getNum() {
        return this.number;
    }
};

let a = {number:20, __proto__:letter};

console.log(a.getNum()); // 20
```

but if `getNum` were changed to arrow function:

```
let letter = {
    getNum: () => this.number
};
```

`a.getNum()` returns `undefined`, why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For regular functions, the value of `this` is (usually) determined when they are invoked.
For arrow functions, the value of `this` is determined when they are defined.

So for the first case, `this` is equal to `a`, because of the `a` in `a.getNum()`. But in the second case, the way you invoked it doesn't matter and `this` is probably equal to the window object (unless `letter` was created inside some other function). `window.number` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Arrow functions do not have their own `this` value. `this` refers to enclosing context.